# Partitioning a drive in Ubuntu for use in a USB dock on a windows system

Tags: hard-drive, fdisk

I am having some issues with a 5TB internal drive I am trying to use on my windows Laptop (attached Via USB in a HDD Docking station).

at first It was having issues detecting the whole drive So I have put it into my Ubuntu system to set it up (partition/format).

steps I have taken:
Partitioned the drive so I have 1 Partition with about 4.7TB on in fdisk on the Ubuntu system (setting it up as Windows .

ran mkfs.ntfs -f on the drive to prepare it.

Ubuntu then detects the drive and I can read/write to it.

the issue is that when I then insert the drive into my USB docker attached to the laptop it does not mount and Displays as RAW in administrative Tools.

If I try to reformat it windows fails to do so.
If I attempt to delete the partition (because it is connected via USB) the drive is only detected as 2TB (which I know is an issue with the USB connection with larger internal drives).

so my question is what steps do I need to take in Ubuntu to partition/format the drive for detection & auto mounting in Windows?

Regards
Chris

Comment: If the USB adapter/docker has a size limitation you won't be able to use a bigger drive with it. Ubuntu isn't magical and won't overcome such limitation.

Comment: Some Docks do not like large drives, but did you use MBR or gpt partitioning? MBR has a 2TB limit, so cannot be used with larger drives. Windows will not create nor see Linux partitions. UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu

Comment: its an odd one because I have used a 5 TB drive in the docker and it worked fine. I have setup the partition as a windows Data (I think is the name without looking at it) in the Hex code I believe it was 11 in FDisk. - I will check if it setup as MBR as this may be the issue.